# 404 error in loading image: Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### **When I am doing ?**

In my Laravel 5.1 code, I created the Project with the name of SampleApplication...with the below path

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\
```

Then after successful registration following directories are being created.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\Users

C:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\Users\{UserName}
C:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\Users\{UserName}\Profile
C:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\Users\{UserName}\Profile\User.png
```

So far everything is ok.

### **What's the problem ?**

In the dashboard page, I am trying to show the image like below.

```
<img src="{{url('/Users/' . auth()->user()->UserName . '/Profile/' . 
            auth()->user()->UserImage)}}" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
```

This produces the below path.

```
http://localhost/SampleApplication/public/Users/UserName/Profile/user.png
```

### **What's the error ?**

This is giving 404 error for the above image.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Where does the public come from?

Comment: I think `url` Helper method is producing that. Please check the `img` tag

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\Users\{UserName}\Profile\User.png   is missing the public folder....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Laravel url default to public/, so for Laravel 5 or 5.1 rename the server.php in the your Laravel root folder to index.php and copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder.

Give a try, It Should work!!

Comment: why not simply save the images inside public_path() ? ... That's far more easy

Comment: yes save image in public path and call image with asset() function as asset will default route to public path.like this asset('/img/profile/users.png')